# MS Access: Join first occurrence to first and second occurrence to second

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

Example: I have this first table,

[image: Table1]

And this second table,

[image: Table2]

I would like a query to join these two tables according to the number and name. However, since the number and name aren't always unique, I end up with multiple combinations. I want the first occurrence in 1st table to match up with the first occurrence in the 2nd table, and 2nd occurrence with the second as shown below:

[image: Result]

Any ideas to solving this problem are appreciated :)

Comment: You can't reliably count occurrences if the table doesn't have a primary key, since it's not ordered. Start by adding one.

Comment: Is it possible to add a primary key if there are duplicates?

Comment: Sounds like you need an introduction to database systems. No, a primary key can not contain duplicate entries, as it's used to distinguish and order entries.

Comment: That's why I asked this, then which column would my primary key be on if I don't have any unique values

Comment: You _add_ one...

Comment: I think you both misunderstood each other, even though Erik's advice is correct.  Add an **AutoNumber** field and **mark it as Primary Key**.  The database will automatically assign unique values even to existing rows, even if there are duplicate rows.  (To be thorough, you could also have added a primary key manually, but it would require more steps:  add a new column, manual input of distinct values, followed by adding the primary key constraint afterward.  I assume that is what your original question/concern was about.)

Answer (score 2):

Add an autonumber field to each table. Designating as primary key is not required. If your data is in SQLServer backend, I have no idea how you create unique identifier field.

I modified field names so they are not the same in both tables.

Then build queries:

Query1

```
SELECT ID1, Number1, Name1, DCount("*","Table1","Name1 = '" & [Name1] & "' AND Number1=" & [Number1] & " AND ID1<=" & [ID1]) AS GrpSeq1
FROM Table1;
```

Query2

```
SELECT ID2, Number2, Name2, Letter, DCount("*","Table2","Name2 = '" & [Name2] & "' AND Number2=" & [Number2] & " AND ID2<=" & [ID2]) AS GrpSeq2
FROM Table2;
```

Query3

```
SELECT Query1.Number1, Query1.Name1, Query1.GrpSeq1, Query2.Letter
FROM Query2 RIGHT JOIN Query1 ON (Query2.Number2 = Query1.Number1) AND (Query2.Name2 = Query1.Name1) AND (Query2.GrpSeq2 = Query1.GrpSeq1);
```

I think there is a way to do the same with a nested SQL instead of the DCount(). Either way, expect slow performance with large dataset.

All in one:

```
SELECT Query1.Number1, Query1.Name1, Query1.GrpSeq1, Query2.Letter
FROM (SELECT Table2.ID2, Table2.Number2, Table2.Name2, DCount("*","Table2","Name2 = '" & [Name2] & "' AND Number2=" & [Number2] & " AND ID2<=" & [ID2]) AS GrpSeq2, Table2.Letter FROM Table2) AS Query2 
RIGHT JOIN (SELECT Table1.ID1, Table1.Number1, Table1.Name1, DCount("*","Table1","Name1 = '" & [Name1] & "' AND Number1=" & [Number1] & " AND ID1<=" & [ID1]) AS GrpSeq1 FROM Table1) AS Query1 
ON (Query2.GrpSeq2 = Query1.GrpSeq1) AND (Query2.Name2 = Query1.Name1) AND (Query2.Number2 = Query1.Number1);
```